# Objective c, downloading, checking and keeping available a plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, asihttprequest

Okay, I'm having a bit of a mental block today/this week, so I'm probably being stupid but I can't get this to work. So, any advice/help as always would be hugely appreciated...

I need my iPhone app, on request to download a plist file from a server just once and have it available any time the app loads up (IE it only needs to be downloaded once in reality). But I really don't think I am doing it right... I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to get the file and this is running in a separate thread to allow a progress bar to update. The download is started either on first run or on request (at the moment).

I am not getting any errors and the server is being contacted, however I don't know if/where the file is being saved to. My tests seem to suggest the file is not getting downloaded.

So I guess my questions are:

- Where should I save the file? Are there any rules to this or will it be held within the app itself on the phone?
- Will this file be available any time the app is run once it is downloaded?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Some code below:

```
-(void)getPlist
{
    NSArray *docpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [docpaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:plistURL];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:documentsDirectory];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progbar];
    [request startSynchronous];
}
```

Thanks in advance/apologies if this is stupidly n00bish, still very much getting the hang of this Objective-C business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ASIHTTPRequest just use it's buildin caching system. Don't rollout your own. It's quite simple and easy to manage

> ASIHTTPRequest can automatically store
>   downloaded data in a cache for use
>   later. This can be helpful in many
>   situations:
>
> You want to have access to the data
>   when there is no internet connection
>   and you can’t download it again You
>   want to download something only if it
>   has changed since you last downloaded
>   it The content you are working with
>   will never change, so you only want to
>   download it once

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache

To answer your orignal question(s)

**Where should I save the file? Are there any rules to this or will it be held within the app itself on the phone?**

Just save it to the documents directory of your applications. Its sandboxed.

**Will this file be available any time the app is run once it is downloaded?**

Yes. But if the user deleted your app and reinstalled it all your cached files will be deleted. Handle the situation.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

I don't see anything wrong with your current implementation. If you run into problems check your request object for error and/or check the return HTTP StatusCode `int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];`

Get your documents path to your (internal on your device) path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the great/quick answer. Shall have a look into the caching ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: I'm glad that this answer helped you. Dont forget to vote helpful answers up ;)

Comment: I shall do in a bit once I have figured it :)
Whilst I'm at it, regarding the download destination path the ASIHTTP docs have examples such as: [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.txt"]
So, I'm a bit confused as to where the documents directory is. (sorry for my million and 1 questions here!)

Comment: It's not the path on the desktop! I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Hence I got uber confused! Got it working now :D Thanks fot the great response. I did however need to use the answer from @benzado also.

Answer (score 1):

I think the download destination path needs to be *a path to a file*, not just the directory to save the file in. Try this:

```
-(void)getPlist
{
    NSArray *docpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [docpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // path to the new destination file
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.bar"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:plistURL];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:path]; // use the file path
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progbar];
    [request startSynchronous];
}
```